# Why does Harvey Dent hate Bruce Wayne?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

In The Dark Knight, Harvey Dent was never really a fan of Bruce Wayne from the start, as evidenced by him giving him weird and dirty looks.

My question is **Why?** Is it something that Bruce did (and did they explain it in the movie) or does Harvey just not like Bruce?

Comment: Because Dent is an upright member of society and Wayne is a gadabout prat who uses his money and influence to bed supermodels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few things going on in the [dinner scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfcemNhlqyA) where Dent first meets Bruce in person, notably the fact that Bruce appears to be going out of his way to impress Dent's date, Rachel. He's evidently arranged a '*coincidental'* meeting at a restaurant (that he just happens to own - Rachel even accuses him of having bought it only a few weeks ago in the novelisation) and bringing a floozy along with him (a world famous ballerina, no less, who'll be headlining the ballet performance that Dent is taking Rachel to later that week), presumably to make her jealous. Harvey is simultaneously threatened by Bruce's long-standing friendship with Rachel, suspicious that Bruce is actually trying to woo her and (even if he's not), intimidated that Bruce may have gone to the time, effort and expense of buying an entire restaurant just to screw with her.

Obviously *we know* that Bruce is actually there to try to size up Dent as a person, to determine whether he's crooked before deciding to support him financially and to gauge whether to throw his, not inconsiderable resources behind his campaign to clean up Gotham.

In short, Bruce is going out of his way to be *Bruce Wayne, noted dilettante & playboy* when in reality, he's there to see whether Dent is a potential ally in his war on crime. Alienating Dent (a little) is actually part of his plan.

Comment: why is an accomplished ballerina a floozy?

Comment: @releseabe - Because she's out on a date with a billionaire solely for the purposes of making his ex jealous? You're right though, she might be a wholesome young lady who thinks that Bruce is 'the one' and will be astounded when he doesn't call her the next day.

Comment: all i am saying is a ballerina is a very demanding, non-floozy profession. i am no expert but "floozy" to me means, more or less, a gold-digger or a border-line, if high-priced, hooker/escort. a prima ballerina, on the other hand has her own money, and perhaps a choice of more than billionaire and countless millionaires to date.; she is would not pick the one with most money if she did not also like him a lot.

Comment: @releseabe - Historically ballerinas have been extensively'sponsored' by wealthy businessmen and government officials. That has included enjoying the pleasure of their company.

Comment: just as sportsmen like baseball players, etc. make more now, i assume so do ballerinas. but even if such sponsorships continue, i can  assure you someone at her level had higher requirements that merely the ability to pay for her time.

Comment: @releseabe - possibly of interest;  https://www.ibtimes.co.uk/bolshoi-volochkova-iksanov-prostitution-ballerina-448256. Still going on today